# Using Guice to inject dependencies into an Android activity's constructor

Tags: android, guice, roboguice

Does anybody know of a way to use Guice to inject dependencies into the constructor of an Activity in Android?  It looks like activities normally have only the default constructor so that the platform can easily create a new instance.  While it is easy enough to have a singleton to reference the injector and get dependencies that way it is less clean and introduces a bit of static state.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I don't know how I missed this!

https://github.com/roboguice/roboguice

Comment: Looks cool. Did you use it already? Would you share a bit of your experience with it?

Comment: Can you be more specific about how it is slow please? 

From the app list using it I'm only able to test geobeagle and I don't feel it slow

Comment: RoboGuice is not slow at all and used in a whole bunch of successful applications in the Android market. If you  have any problems join the mailing list.

Comment: If you're concerned about Java Reflection being slow on some Android devices, give a shot to [AndroidAnnotations](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations) :) It's a compile time alternative to RoboGuice (which I also like!)